# ¿Cómo se suman los valores de una estructura en C?

Tags: c

Tengo que hacer un programa para un almacén con sus reportes de existencias, pero no sé cómo sumar todos los valores de las existencias dentro de la estructura. Aquí está el código completo:

```c
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

struct producto {

    int id_producto;
    int e;

        }almacen[100];

struct operacion {

    int id_producto;
    int c;
    char factura[100];

        }ventas[100],compras[100];

int main(){

    int n1,n2,i,j,p,q,r,s,t, ne=0;
    int opcion,opcion1;

    p=0;
    q=0;
    t=0;

    do{
        system("clear");
        printf("\n\n \t\t Control de almacén ");
        printf("\n");
        printf("\nMenú\n");
        printf("\n");
        printf("1. Registrar venta.\n");
        printf("2. Registrar compra.\n");
        printf("3. Reportes.\n");
        printf("4. Salir.\n");
        printf("\n");
        printf("Teclear la opción deseada:");
        scanf("%d",&opcion);
        printf("\n");

        switch(opcion){

            case 1:
                system("clear");
                printf("\n");
                printf("       Registro de venta");
                printf("\n");
                printf("\n");

                printf("Cuántas ventas desea registrar? ");
                scanf("%d",&n1);
                printf("\n");

                for (i=q; i<(n1+q); i++) {

                    printf("Ventas %d. \n",i+1);
                    printf("\n");
                    printf("ID del producto: ");
                    scanf("%d", &ventas[i].id_producto);

                    for(j=0; j<=(n2+p); j++){

                        if(ventas[i].id_producto==almacen[j].id_producto){

                            printf("Cantidad: ");
                            scanf("%d", &ventas[i].c);


                            if(ventas[i].c>almacen[j].e){

                                printf("\n");
                                printf("No se cuenta con la cantidad suficiente del producto \n");
                                printf("\n");
                                break;

                                }



                            if(ventas[i].c<=almacen[j].e){

                                printf("Número de factura: ");
                                scanf("%s", ventas[i].factura);
                                printf("\n");



                                almacen[j].e=almacen[j].e-ventas[i].c;

                                }

                            t++;

                        }
                        else
                        {
                                 printf("\n\n Este producto no existe!!!\n");
                         }


                    }

                }

                s=n1+q;
                q=n1;


                break;

            case 2:
                system("clear");
                printf("\n");
                printf("       Registro de compra");
                printf("\n");
                printf("\n");

                printf("Cuantas compras desea registrar? ");
                scanf("%d",&n2);
                printf("\n");

                for (i=p; i<(n2+p); i++) {

                    printf("Compra %d. \n",i+1);
                    printf("\n");
                    printf("ID del producto: ");
                    scanf("%d", &compras[i].id_producto);
                    printf("Cantidad: ");
                    scanf("%d", &compras[i].c);
                    printf("Número de factura: ");
                    scanf("%s", compras[i].factura);
                    printf("\n");

                    almacen[i].id_producto=compras[i].id_producto;
                    almacen[i].e=compras[i].c;

                }

                r=n2+p;
                p=n2;

                break;

            case 3:
                system("clear");
                do{
                    printf("\n");
                    printf("       Menú de reportes");
                    printf("\n");
                    printf("\n");

                    printf("    1. Reporte de almacén.\n");
                    printf("    2. Reporte de compras.\n");
                    printf("    3. Reportes de ventas.\n");
                    printf("    4. Salir.\n");
                    printf("\n");
                    printf("Teclear la opción deseada:");
                    scanf("%d",&opcion1);
                    printf("\n");

                    switch(opcion1){

                        case 1:

                                printf("\n");
                                printf("Reporte de almacén \n");
                                printf("\n");
                                printf("\n");

                                printf("ID del producto   -   Existencia \n");

                                printf("\n");

                            for (i=0; i<r; i++){
                                printf("        %d                %d       \n", almacen[i].id_producto,almacen[i].e);
                                ne=ne+almacen[i].e;
                                }
                                printf("\n\nTotal de items: %d\n", r);
                                printf("Total de existencias: %d\n", ne);
                            break;

                        case 2:


                                printf("\n");
                                printf("Reporte de compras \n");
                                printf("\n");
                                printf("\n");

                                printf("ID del producto   -   Cantidad   -   No. de factura \n");
                                printf("\n");

                            for (i=0; i<r; i++)
                                printf("        %d                %d                %s      \n", compras[i].id_producto,compras[i].c,compras[i].factura);
                                printf("\n\nTotal de items: %d\n", r);
                                printf("\n\nTotal de existencias: %d\n", t);
                                printf("\n");
                                printf("\n");
                            break;

                        case 3:


                                printf("\n");
                                printf("Reporte de ventas \n");
                                printf("\n");
                                printf("\n");

                                printf("ID del producto   -   Cantidad   -   No. de factura \n");
                                printf("\n");

                            for (i=0; i<s; i++)
                                printf("        %d               %d                %s      \n", ventas[i].id_producto,ventas[i].c,ventas[i].factura);
                                 printf("\n\nTotal de items: %d\n", r);
                                printf("\n\nTotal de existencias: %d\n", t);
                            printf("\n");
                            printf("\n");

                            break;

                        case 4:

                            break;

                        default:

                            printf("\n Opción no valida \n");
                    }

                }while(opcion1!=4);

                break;

            case 4:

                break;

            default:
                printf("\n Opción no valida \n");
        }


    } while(opcion!=4);


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Hola tu pregunta no es muy clara, seria bueno mostraras algo de codigo.

Comment: Ok                                 printf("ID del producto   -   Existencia \n");
                                printf("\n");
                            
                            for (i=0; i<r; i++)
                                printf("        %d                %d       \n", almacen[i].id_producto,almacen[i].e);
                                printf("\n\nTotal de items: %d\n", r);
                                printf("\n\nTotal de existencias: %d\n", t);/*Aqui tendria que ir el numero de existencias de todos los productos*/

Comment: Y la estructura es:

Comment: struct producto {
    
    int id_producto;
    int e;
    
        }almacen[100];

Comment: @EphraVital Suele ser recomendable responder a las preguntas que te hacen vía comentario editando tu propia pregunta. StackOverflow no pretende ser un sistema de chat y tenerlo todo organizado en la pregunta hace que sea más sencillo para todos entender el problema.

Answer (score 1):

Hola en base a la informacion proporcionada te falta declarar una variable que lleve la suma del numero de productos en existencia la cual deberia ser declarada fuera del bucle y se deberia estar incrementado cada vez que este iterando el for y que por lo tanto deberia estar dentro un par de llaves.

En el siguiente ejemplo declaro e inicializo 4 elementos por motivos del ejemplo pero tu puedes dejarlo con los 100 elementos iniciales:

```
struct producto
{
    int id_producto;
    int existencia;
}almacen[4];


int main()
{
    int totalElementos=4;
    int numeroExistencias=0;

    almacen[0].id_producto=1001;
    almacen[0].existencia=20;

    almacen[1].id_producto=1002;
    almacen[1].existencia=10;

    almacen[2].id_producto=1003;
    almacen[2].existencia=34;

    almacen[3].id_producto=1004;
    almacen[3].existencia=5;


    printf("ID del producto - Existencia \n");
    for(int i=0;i<totalElementos;i++)
    {
        printf(" %d %d \n", almacen[i].id_producto,almacen[i].existencia);
        numeroExistencias=numeroExistencias+almacen[i].existencia;
    }
   printf("\n\nTotal de items: %d\n", totalElementos);
   printf("\n\nTotal de existencias: %d\n", numeroExistencias);


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: ok gracias, ahora tengo otro problema cuando ingreso el primer valor no hay problema en el reporte si me aparece las existencias pero luego quiero almacenar otro ingreso y vuelve a sumar lo que ya tenia más lo mismo y da un numero muy grade

Comment: @EphraVital Esta nueva duda estaría mejor en una pregunta nueva. En ella publicas el código actual y concretas tus dudas en ese punto. Si no lo haces así va a ser dificil seguir el hilo del tema